# checking whether or not a variable of type double is null or not, generates error

Tags: java, android

I'm just checking if a value of a double variable is null or not, strangely, an error 
raised saying "operator == is undefined for double"?

**Code**:

```
public double getGyro_X() {
    if (this.gyro_X == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+gyro_XIsNullText, ToastdurationShort).show();
    } else {
    return this.gyro_X;
    }
}
```

Comment: is gyro_X a `double` or a `Double`?

Comment: Right, `double` is a primitive type, while `Double` being an Object.

Comment: If you don't want to change your primitive to a `Double` object (as suggested below), you could consider explicitly initializing it to some value that you consider 'invalid'. For example, you could set it to [`Double.Nan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html#NaN), which actually is a constant for the *Not-a-Number* value of the (primitive) `double` type, and check for that in your method (in stead of `null`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then its of type `double` and not of type `Double`..  and double cannot be null

Answer (score 1):

this.gyro_X apparantly is an instance variable, it will be initialized automatically to 0.

If you want to be able to check against null, you'll have to use a Double (= wrapper class for double).

Just for clarity: doubles are primitives, Doubles are objects. Primitives can't be null, so you can't compare them against null. Objects you can compare to null.